# @PropertySource doesn't override properties defined in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-context

If any property is defined in `application.properties`, it cannot be overridden by re-defining it in other `.properties` files using the `@PropertySource` annotation. This bug is only valid if the original value is present in `application.properties`. Any other file (e.g. `app.properties`) will allow to successfully override its values.

E.g.:

`application.properties`:

```
test.application=original
```

`app.properties`:

```
test.app=original
```

`override.properties`:

```
test.application=overridden
test.app=overridden
```

`ApplicationPropertiesConfig.java`:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource(value = {
        "classpath:application.properties",
        "classpath:app.properties",
        "classpath:override.properties"
})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class ApplicationPropertiesConfig {

    private String application;  // == "original"   (BAD)

    private String app;          // == "overridden" (GOOD)

}
```

In the configuration above, the field `application` won't be overridden upon bean creation and will keep its original value defined in `application.properties`.

This was confirmed with the most recent Spring Boot versions: 2.7.11 and 3.0.6.

The same behavior is observed even if `application.properties` is not listed under `@PropertySource` or if the `@PropertySources` annotation is used.

Code reproducing the issue is here: https://github.com/denisab85/spring-property-overriding

> A known workaround is renaming `application.properties` to something else (e.g. `app.properties`). Overriding works normally then. But this will not work in my case due to the size of the project where many classes already rely on the default `application.properties`.
>
>  Source: a comment by Maksim Muruev (mmuruev) in [@PropertySource not overriding in order [SPR-13500]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18078#issuecomment-711850211).

Comment: Overridding works perfectly well, it doesn't work in this case due to `@ConfigurationProperties`. Which are processed very early in the startup process, before `@PropertySource` has been processed. If you want to load additional property files use the `spring.config.additional-location` property (command line property) to specify this and not `@PropertySource`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for your comment. I created a separate branch to test your hypothesis. It appears, the @ConfigurationProperties has nothing to do with the early processing of `application.properties`. Even without this annotation, the same issue takes place: https://github.com/denisab85/spring-property-overriding/tree/NoConfigurationProperties

Comment: `application.properties` (+profiled) has "slightly higher" precedence than `@PropertySource` (3rd lowest vs. 2nd lowest precedence) due to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config ..which makes it not a bug but rather a feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Spring Boot and not plain Spring. Which has certain, opinionated views. As I mentioned in my comment you shouldn't be using `@PropertySource` but specify the additional configuration files through `--spring.config.additional-locations` or (which I didn't mention) add them through an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

If you would inject the `Environment` into your test and obtain the `PropertySources` from it you can print them out to the console. You will then see the following.

```
ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource {name='configurationProperties'}
MapPropertySource {name='test'}
MapPropertySource {name='Inlined Test Properties'}
PropertiesPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}
OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}
RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''}
ResourcePropertySource {name='class path resource [override.properties]'}
ResourcePropertySource {name='class path resource [app.properties]'}
ResourcePropertySource {name='class path resource [application.properties]'}
```

This is, regardless of using `@ConfigurationProperties`. Spring Boot will always load the `application.properties` before anything else, so before the `@PropertySource`s in some `@Configuration` files (or where ever you choose to place them). So this file **always** takes precedence, due to Spring Boot.

Now as I stated you can circumvent this by either specifying configuration locations at startup by adding `--spring.config.additional-location=classpath:app.properties,classpath:override.properties` if you do that the output will change to the following:

```
ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource {name='configurationProperties'}
MapPropertySource {name='test'}
MapPropertySource {name='Inlined Test Properties'}
SimpleCommandLinePropertySource {name='commandLineArgs'}
PropertiesPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}
OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}
RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'class path resource [override.properties]' via location 'classpath:override.properties''}
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'class path resource [app.properties]' via location 'classpath:app.properties''}
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/''}
```

And now your tests will pass (and you will see the overrides will work).

Finally you could also use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to add these files as property sources and have them load automatically by specifying it in a `spring.factories` file.

```java
package com.example.springpropertyoverriding;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource;

public class AdditionalConfigurationFilesAdder implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private static final String[] locations =
            new String[] { "classpath:app.properties", "classpath:override.properties"};

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        for (String location : locations) {
            try {
                ResourcePropertySource source = new ResourcePropertySource(location);
                propertySources.addAfter("random", source);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can reference this in a `META-INF/spring.factories` file so that it will add the resources.

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.springpropertyoverriding.AdditionalConfigurationFilesAdder
```

And now again when running the tests the output will be (more or less) the same as with specifying `--spring.config.additional-location` and the tests will pass.

You have to realize the fact that you are using Spring Boot and that comes with some opinionated views on what to load when. The order is actually also explained in the [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). Which clearly shows that `application.properties` always takes precedence over `@PropertySource`.

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Later property sources can override the values defined in earlier ones. Sources are considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Default properties (specified by setting `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`).
> 2. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes. Please note that such property sources are not added to the `Environment` until the application context is being refreshed. This is too late to configure certain properties such as `logging.*` and `spring.main.*` which are read before refresh begins.
> 3. Config data (such as application.properties files).
> 4. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that has properties only in `random.*.`
> 5. OS environment variables.
> 6. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> 7. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`.
> 8. `ServletContext` init parameters.
> 9. `ServletConfig` init parameters.
> 10. Properties from `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> 11. Command line arguments.
>     12.properties attribute on your tests. Available on `@SpringBootTest` and the test annotations for testing a particular slice of your application.
> 12. `@TestPropertySource` annotations on your tests.
> 13. Devtools global settings properties in the `$HOME/.config/spring-boot` directory when devtools is active.
>     Config data files are considered in the following order:

> 1. Application properties packaged inside your jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 2. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 3. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 4. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).

So in short no it is not a bug it is described and intended behavior you are seeing when using Spring Boot.

Comment: Both proposed solutions work as described. One of them (using AdditionalConfigurationFilesAdder) I implemented in my demo: https://github.com/denisab85/spring-property-overriding/tree/With-AdditionalConfigurationFilesAdder
Thanks, M.Deinum